# Nesting Try-Except statements to dim lights and then eventually shut them off

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to dim the lights after a period of no movement, then eventually shut them off completely after another period of time. The problem i'm facing is that when it's shutoff it should only have the option to turn on again, not to randomly dim coming from an off-state. Code below:

```
    async def main(self):
    while True:
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(self.movement_detected(), timeout=10)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            state_off = {"state": "off"}
            state_dim = {"brightness":50, "state": "ON"} 
            print('TIMEOUT...DIMMING ' + topic)
            async with Client(self.broker) as client:
                await client.publish(topic, orjson.dumps(state_dim))
            try:
                await asyncio.wait_for(self.movement_detected(), timeout=10)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                print('TIMEOUT...TURNING OFF ' + topic)
                async with Client(self.broker) as client:
                    await client.publish(topic, orjson.dumps(state_off))
```

When I run it I get:

```
ON
ON
ON 
TIMEOUT...DIMMING /light
TIMEOUT...TURNING OFF /light
TIMEOUT...DIMMING /light
TIMEOUT...TURNING OFF /light
TIMEOUT...DIMMING /light
TIMEOUT...TURNING OFF /light
TIMEOUT...DIMMING /light
```

Which means I assume means I messed up the try-except statements, does anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Found a work-around myself, do not think it is the most aesthetically pleasing but it appears to function.

```
async def main(self):
    count = 0
    while True:
        if count == 1:
            try:
                await asyncio.wait_for(self.movement_detected(), timeout=60)
                count = 0
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                print('TIMEOUT...TURNING OFF ' + topic)
                count = 1
                async with Client(self.broker) as client:
                    await client.publish(topic, orjson.dumps(state_off))
        else:    
            try:
                await asyncio.wait_for(self.movement_detected(), timeout=900)
                count = 0
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                count = 1
                state_off = {"state": "off"}
                state_dim = {"brightness":50, "state": "ON"} 
            
                print('TIMEOUT...DIMMING ' + topic)
                async with Client(self.broker) as client:
                    await client.publish(topic, orjson.dumps(state_dim))
```

This prevents it from dimming from an off-state, it can only dim from an on-state.